# SELECT * FROM db value defined by customer in a form

Tags: mysql, database

i've a form and a client puts in the form a value for the variable "PRICE", for example 10

I'd like to do a function in my .php file that do this

```
SELECT * FROM $table WHERE price = "the value put in from the client" (10 in this case)
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you asking how to write PHP code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use sanitization of user submitted data and prepared statements,  in order to avoid serious hacks.

```
$price=filter_var($_POST['price'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //USER SUBMITTED sanitization stage 1.

$query=$dbh->prepare("SELECT *  FROM $table WHERE price=?;");
$query->execute(array($price));
```